# Tensorflow Federated tutorial in Google Colab giving errors in the initialization code snippet

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

Here is the cell that needs to be run before starting the tutorial.

```
#@test {"skip": true}

# tensorflow_federated_nightly also bring in tf_nightly, which
# can causes a duplicate tensorboard install, leading to errors.
!pip uninstall --yes tensorboard tb-nightly

!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow_federated_nightly
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest_asyncio
!pip install --quiet tb-nightly  # or tensorboard, but not both

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

It is giving out following errors:

```
ERROR: tensorflow 2.4.1 requires tensorboard~=2.4, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.4.1 has requirement gast==0.3.3, but you'll have gast 0.4.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.4.1 has requirement grpcio~=1.32.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.34.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.4.1 has requirement h5py~=2.10.0, but you'll have h5py 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
```

Need help resolving this. I am not much familiar with libraries and classes on Tensorflow.

Comment: Do the rest of the cells in the colab not work? I believe pip says 'error' but the packages actually installed.

Comment: I think you are right. It worked, I checked them all after your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the console says there was an error, the pip packages should have been installed correctly.

This happens because the notebooks use `tensorflow-federated-nightly`, which depends on an installs `tf-nightly` overwriting the base `tensorflow` install. However `pip` still thinks the TFF dependencies will conflict with the now overwritten TensorFlow core package.

Adding `tensorflow` to the `!pip uninstall` list may make this error go away, but the functionality of the notebook won't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can import tensorflow federated like the following. It solved my error. I tried to follow Federated Learning for Image Classification and while I was trying to import tensorflow_federated it was always giving me error.

```
from tensorflow_federated import python as tff
```