# Issues in setting up the environment for TensorFlow Federated on Colab

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am new to Federated Learning, and I am trying to get started with TensorFlow Federated. While working on the tutorial "Federated Learning for Image Classification" on Colab, I tried to install TensorFlow Federated, but was met with these errors:

```
ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 requires tensorboard~=2.5, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement grpcio~=1.34.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.37.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement keras-nightly~=2.5.0.dev, but you'll have keras-nightly 2.6.0.dev2021062500 which is incompatible.
ERROR: spacy 2.2.4 has requirement tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0, but you'll have tqdm 4.28.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pymc3 3.11.2 has requirement cachetools>=4.2.1, but you'll have cachetools 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: fbprophet 0.7.1 has requirement tqdm>=4.36.1, but you'll have tqdm 4.28.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow-privacy 0.6.1 has requirement attrs>=21.2.0, but you'll have attrs 19.3.0 which is incompatible.
```

After installing the versions of the libraries mentioned here, I found that there still exist some internal conflicts with the installed libraries. Has anyone else faced this issue? Would be great to get some pointers on this!

Comment: Does the rest of the note fail to run? This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66182614/tensorflow-federated-tutorial-in-google-colab-giving-errors-in-the-initializatio

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett Yes, there are issues in importing TensorFlow Federated, as __version__ from Keras is not imported

Comment: Could the question be extended with the Python code that raises an error, along with the exception and stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following commands to reset the environment:

```py
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip uninstall tf-nightly
!pip uninstall tensorflow-federated
!pip install tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow-federated
!pip install tensorflow-federated-nightly
```