# Installation errors in Tensorflow Federated tutorial in Google Colab

Tags: installation, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I am a new learner to Federated Learning. I tried to start with [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=8BKyHkMxKHfV) "Federated Learning for Image Classification" on Colab but met some problems. When I installed TensorFlow and TensorFlow Federated,

```
#@test {"skip": true}

# tensorflow_federated_nightly also bring in tf_nightly, which
# can causes a duplicate tensorboard install, leading to errors.
!pip uninstall --yes tensorboard tb-nightly

!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated-nightly
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tb-nightly  # or tensorboard, but not both

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

some error occurs

```
ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 requires tensorboard~=2.5, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement grpcio~=1.34.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.37.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement keras-nightly~=2.5.0.dev, but you'll have keras-nightly 2.7.0.dev2021071300 which is incompatible.
ERROR: spacy 2.2.4 has requirement tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0, but you'll have tqdm 4.28.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pymc3 3.11.2 has requirement cachetools>=4.2.1, but you'll have cachetools 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: fbprophet 0.7.1 has requirement tqdm>=4.36.1, but you'll have tqdm 4.28.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow-privacy 0.6.1 has requirement attrs>=21.2.0, but you'll have attrs 19.3.0 which is incompatible.
```

I see some similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66182614/tensorflow-federated-tutorial-in-google-colab-giving-errors-in-the-initializatio)  regarding these errors and then run the rest of cells. However, when it comes to code

```
import collections

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
```

Errors occur again:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-3-a23308ec3f7c> in <module>()
3 import numpy as np
4 import tensorflow as tf
----> 5 import tensorflow_federated as tff
  6 
  7 np.random.seed(0)

28 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras/__init__.py in <module>()
  8 import sys as _sys
  9 
---> 10 from keras import __version__
 11 from keras.api._v2.keras import __internal__
 12 from keras.api._v2.keras import activations

ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'keras' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py)
```

I am not familiar with TensorFlow Federated. Has anyone else faced same issue? Need pointers to resolve this.

Comment: I am facing the same error, could you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a clean runtime and add a code section with the following:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow keras -y
```

Run this before you run anything else, and restart your runtime. Then you can run the rest of the tutorial.